# How to create a copy of a linked database in LibreOffice Base

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-base

I have a connection to a Microsoft Access to Libreoffice Base using a JDBC connection. When I save the database in Base it retains the connection.

I want to create a copy as a standalone Base database which includes all the imported tables, so that it no longer looks to the Access file for its data.

How do I achieve this clone?

Comment: Try creating a new database using the built-in Firebird or HSQLDB, place windows side by side and simply drag and drop tables and queries into the appropriate sections of the new database - a simple wizard should start as you drag.

Comment: @JohnSUN Thanks, that does get the table across to a new database. However I am not able to make changes to tables that have existing data. In particular I want to add a new Primary Key with auto-populated data. Can this be done? I I try and do anything with th copied table Base throws an error, not liking any table changes.

Comment: Are you talking about Firebird? Yes, there is no perfection in the world. Please take a look [**here**](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=firebird%20primary) - it seems that someone suggested a working workaround for just such situations.

Comment: I'm using HSQLDB as that seemed to be the default for new databases. The link you gave does not seem to point to a workaround but a list of bugs(?)

Comment: Yes, you're right, it's a list of errors. Somewhere in the discussion of one of them, a way was proposed to bypass the error of creating a primary key - I don’t remember now who and what suggested, you need to look through all the discussions. Okay, but what if you first create an empty table with add a new Primary Key with auto-populated, and only then use drag and drop, only add data?